# Multitouch and ccTouchesMoved, laggy movement

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a pong game, and I use finger to move paddle.
It all goes smooth and well when there is one finger. But when I want to control two players, two paddles, one paddle moves fine but another paddle moves very laggy, if at all. When second paddle starts moving my first paddle freezes. How do I make both movements feel smooth and responsive?

I have multitouch enabled in my Director.

Here is my code for touches:

```
- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    CGRect leftTouchZone = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 320);
    CGRect rightTouchZone = CGRectMake(430, 0, 50, 320);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(leftTouchZone, location))
    {
        CGPoint tempLoc = location;
        tempLoc.x = paddle1.position.x;
        paddle1.position = tempLoc;
    }

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rightTouchZone, location))
    {
        CGPoint tempLoc = location;
        tempLoc.x = paddle2.position.x;
        paddle2.position = tempLoc;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt you look through all your touches objects instead of just grabbing any object? If you are moving 2 touches at the same time, only one will get the touches moved event.

```
- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* myTouch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
        CGRect leftTouchZone = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 320);
        CGRect rightTouchZone = CGRectMake(430, 0, 50, 320);

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(leftTouchZone, location))
        {
            CGPoint tempLoc = location;
            tempLoc.x = paddle1.position.x;
            paddle1.position = tempLoc;
        }

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(rightTouchZone, location))
        {
            CGPoint tempLoc = location;
            tempLoc.x = paddle2.position.x;
            paddle2.position = tempLoc;
        }
    }
```